# Clueless on how to put my PHP project in the Internet

Tags: php

Good day!

I've searched for many sites on how I could deploy my PHP projet in the internet but I don't know how to do it because I am confused with some of the technical terms.

You see, I am using xampp for my local web server. Now I want to put it in the internet. I found some free web hosting sites so i've decided to upload all my htdocs files inside it.. But how can I put the xampp (apache server) and my mysql database on it? I'm confused. Please help. A step-by-step procedure of what should i do could be really helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: export db in phpmyadmin on localhost/phpmyadmin and import it in the phpmyadmin of your hoster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you buy a domain-name and space, connect them using the NS settings
   If you are using a free, then the settings are already okay.
2. Export the database from your XAMP.
3. Login to the remote server. There you'll find PHPMyAdmin. Import the database.
4. Upload the file.
5. Make sure file listing is off. That is if a user goes to any directory he can not see the file list!

Done :)

Comment: Through you're help, I've uploaded my website successfully on the internet. I've use filezilla to help me upload my file.. Thank you once again! :)

Answer (score 3):

Get a hosting account (try www.bluehost.com for instance).They will set you up with a Linux server and MySQL. You don't have to install Apache or MySQL, you will use whatever they've got. All you need to do is upload your PHP files to the right folder, setup your database on their server and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Simplifying a bit, there are two ways you can get your site online.

First, you could purchase or rent a server that is yours and yours alone. This is commonly called "dedicated hosting" and costs somewhere around $100 / month. If you choose this option, you have your own server housed in a datacenter somewhere, and you must install Apache, MySQL, and any other server software you care to use.

I doubt, given what you've described, you have chosen this option.

Second, you could rent "shared hosting" from any one of the dozens of hosting providers out there. If you do this, with a typical cost of $2 to $10 per month, the hosting provider is administering the server. You have ***no direct access*** at all. Your only access is through the tools they provide.

Given that, how specifically you can upload files is up to them (is it FTP? SSH? a horrifying web-based upload tool of some kind?)  Similarly, how you access your MySQL databases (assuming they offer MySQL databases) is entirely up to them as well.

Many providers now use a tool called cPanel for this administration, so you may try browsing to www.example.com/cPanel (using your domain) on the off chance that works. If not, though, follow the instructions your host provides. Only they can correctly describe how their setup works.

Answer (score 1):

The hosting will be already having apache and mysql installed you only have to put your files thats it

Comment: what do i need to put? Only the files?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you contact your webhosting site. The web hosting needs to host php, and mysql. Then you can upload your files to their web server, and copy your mysql database to their mysql server.

Comment: You can use Mysql Administrator to backup and restore your database. This is a free util offered at mysql.com

Answer (score 1):

- You do not need to transfer xampp to your host: apache and mysql are running on nearly every server
- Upload all your files in your htdocs directory via ftp to your server
- To transfer your database, use phpMyAdmin. It is installed with xampp and alos installed on nearly every server. In phpMyAdmin, use the export/import functionality
- In your php file where you connect to the db change the login settings to the settings the hoster gave you

That should work...

Answer (score 1):

Hosting Company already have setup for apache,php, mysql. All you need to uploads all your 
files from xampp htdocs to a right folder like public_html using a ftp software like
[filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/). They also provide a control panel like using which you can manage your mysql
database and all others settings like directory permission.